# python mock module throws exception

Tags: python, mocking

I am very new in this forum. So please let me know if I am not asking question in right format, etc.

I am basically trying to follow along documentation for mock module in python
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/mock-1.0.1.pdf

But if I do the following I get an error.
any help?
I am using python 2.7.3

```
>>> from mock import Mock
>>> mock = Mock()
>>> mock.method(1, 2, 3, test=’wow’)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    mock.method(1, 2, 3, test=’wow’)
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I do not use the KWARGS it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `'` instead of `’`

```py
mock.method(1, 2, 3, test='wow')
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I did cut and paste from pdf document, and that messed up. Thanks a lot again Pablo.